# Python: Tor not connecting with a certain website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tor

I am trying to access a specific website with Python and Tor, but somehow it just loads forever and no response comes.

```
import requests
import socks
import socket

url = 'http://www.ryanair.com'

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

response = requests.get(url)
#no response comes
```

Some weeks ago it was working. In addition, the same code works still fine for other sites. 
My guess would be that it is not a problem on my side, but on the website's side, but I have no clue what can be wrong.

Any ideas of what can be and how it could be solved?

---

**Edit:**

If I run the command:

```
curl --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150 -vvv http://www.ryanair.com
```

I get:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.ryanair.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9150 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.ryanair.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found : Moved Temporarily
< Location: https://www.ryanair.com/
< Connection: close
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Trying with https:

```
$ curl --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150 -vvv https://www.ryanair.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.ryanair.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9150 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: www.ryanair.com
* Server certificate: GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.ryanair.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
#...and it remains here
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I just tried to load this website directly at the Tor browser and it will also keep loading without end.

Comment: Since it doesn't work in tor browser either and you've tried a number of exits then they're most likely blocking tor traffic so it'll hang until the connection times out.

Comment: As far as I understood, Tor will change the IP every 5min. So even if they blocked it, this block should not work anymore after 5min, should it?

Comment: Tor doesn't necessarily change IP every 5 minutes. But they're blocking all Tor IP addresses since they're all known so you're most likely not going to have success connecting over Tor anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to run diagnostics without access to your proxy server, but in general, if you're debugging a request, `curl` is your most invaluable tool.

This should help:

```
curl --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150 -vvv http://www.ryanair.com
```

The `-vvv` will show you information about the request and the response. That will show you whether your request is well structured or whether the server response is at fault.

Comment: Thanks @cwallenpoole . I updated the question with your suggestion. It says `HTTP/1.1 302 Found : Moved Temporarily`...